# Блымает логотип при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-router-dom

У меня есть **Header**, который отображается на большинстве страниц, у него есть логотип.
Сперва с сервера подгружается объект, где лежит ссылка на иконку, и после она вставляется в `img src={url}`

```
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/2702/2702602.svg?token=exp=1614405873~hmac=3772d6a8741ca2cfffc69e27b3de00a5"
    ).then((res) => setUrl(res.url));
  });
  return <img src={url} />
```

Так вот моя проблема заключается в том, что теперь при переходе между страницами у меня блымает картинка.
Если бы я загружал картинку напрямую в тег
`<img src={link to the image} />` то проблема исчезает, но мне нужно именно сперва получать ссылку с сервера.

Один из вариантов решения, который пришел мне в голову, это использовать единственный экземпляр **Header**, например так:

```
     <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Но тогда, если **Header** будет отличаться на разных страницах, мне придется переполнять компонент лишней логикой и чужими обязанностями.

Например, на странице **Home** мне нужно отобразить модалку, кнопка открытия модалки находится в **Header**, мне будет неудобно передавать пропсы из **Header** в **Home page**.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-brook-vjy8e?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

А почему Header занимается получением ссылки? По хорошему, Вы должны в Header передавать ссылку на логотип в качестве пропсы.

Получайте ссылку на картинку в компоненте выше, или в Вашем случае - в App.

```
const App = () => {
   const [logoURL, setLogoURL] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetch(
       "https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/2702/2702602.svg?token=exp=1614405873~hmac=3772d6a8741ca2cfffc69e27b3de00a5"
     ).then((res) => setLogoURL(res.url));
   }, []);
   
   return (
      <Router>
        <Header logo={logoURL} />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
};
```

Но именно Ваша проблема связана с тем, что в `useEffect` нет параметра `deps`, из-за этого на каждый рендер у Вас запрашивается картинка заново.

Comment: Да, при таком подходе (когда есть только один экземпляр Header) у меня все работало, но возникают трудности с дальнейшим взаимодействием с Header. Например если у меня в зависимости от страницы меняется Header, но логотип всегда остается неизменным, тогда как мне правильно организовать код?

Comment: Да и хотелось бы видеть правильную иерархию, типа `<Page><Header /></Page>`, взамен `<App><Header /><Page /></App>`